# Random Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I have this program that works well with out any error
and at random time, I get this error page.

**Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.**

in any page I try to visit. This error persists for few minutes and clears off later on its own as the same pages displays as expected.

**Few Routing code**

`Route::get('/', 'indexController@index')->name('index-post-page');
Route::get('/login', 'indexController@login')->name('index-login-page');
Route::get('/post/{post_id}/{title}','indexController@SinglePost')->name('SinglePost-page');
Route::get('/account/contributor/dashboard','indexController@ContributorsDashboard')->name('page-contributor-admin');
Route::prefix('account')->group(function() {
Route::get('/', 'indexController@accountDashboard')->name('admin-home-page');
Route::get('/nonadmin', 'indexController@accountDashboardNonAdmin')->name('page-non-admin');
Route::get('/nonadmin', 'indexController@ContributorsDashboard')->name('page-non-admin');
Route::get('/admin/add/category', 'indexController@AddCategory')->name('page.add.category');
Route::get('/admin/view/category', 'indexController@viewCategory')->name('page.load.all.category');
Route::get('/admin/audit/featured', 'indexController@AuditFeatured')->name('page.feature.unfeature.post');
Route::get('/post/notification/data/{contributor_id}', 'indexController@PostNotificationReportData')->name('admin.post.notification.report.data');
})`

Have checked the error log and all i see is ERROR 404 (page not found)- though the page is existing

I want to believe this is not a program issue but a server issue as i have hosted same script on another server and everything went well.

But i dont know exactly what to tell the server administrator that causes the error or what i need him to fix.

URL: [program link](http://stag.armacademy.com.ng)

LOGIN LINK: [AUTOMATIC_LOGIN](http://stag.armacademy.com.ng/login.php)

Can someone give me a hint or what exactly is causing this random ERROR 404

Comment: _i have this program that works perfectly and at random I get this error page._ I wouldn't say it runs perfetly then ;-)

Comment: It seems to be a problem with reading the .htacess file, it keeps redirecting to `/public/login` where normally it would only be to `/login`

Comment: Adjust your .htaccess and double check file ownerships and permissions.

Comment: I actually made the page to redirect to the login page until they login from another application on the same domain name @Sérgio Reis

Comment: well, unless you show us any **code**, we can not do anything but guess....

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann what level of codes do u want me to show u. Cos i used Laravel and it have alot of codes already. i can share the codes online for you to see

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. Let's start with your routes file and which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Virtual **Login Page:** http://stag.armacademy.com.ng/login.php

Comment: SO does not want to see links to your code we want to see your code posted in the question.

Comment: Added part of my route to the question.

Full codes to the route found here
http://collabedit.com/v2283

Answer (score 2):

Make sure, in your apache config, your web root is pointed to the public directory rather than the application root.

```
<VirtualHost [2001:db8::a00:20ff:fea7:ccea]:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/docs/host.example.com/public"
    ServerName host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/host.example.com-error_log"
    TransferLog "logs/host.example.com-access_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I am not having any issue with the application pointing to **/public** , the problem  is the ERROR 404 it keeps showing that error at random times and goes off at random time

**Login Page:** http://stag.armacademy.com.ng/login.php

Comment: this or the .htaccess is most likely your issue. What is different from the host where it is working?

Comment: @VictoriaFriday /public should not be in URL. You are potentially exposing parts of your application that should never be served. To clarify, make sure the document root in your VirtualHost directive includes the /public in the path.

`<VirtualHost [2001:db8::a00:20ff:fea7:ccea]:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/docs/host.example.com/public"
    ServerName host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/host.example.com-error_log"
    TransferLog "logs/host.example.com-access_log"
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: @happymacarts No difference. Same code on the other server.

Comment: @Jason Thanks a bunch for ur security tips. I am not having any issue making the VirtualHost point to the public folder directly. My problem is why does all of a sudden, every page on the server returns ERROR 404. After few mins, everything works normal. Thats my focus problem now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply because your laravel application would run better without the /public, especially when you run from a life server.

I know it sounds tricky to believe but make your webserver point to public_html/public/ and your application would run perfectly without any more ERROR 404.

This is inline with what @jason suggested.

Comment: Thanks a bunch this solved my problem.. Making the webserver point to public_html/public solve the whole problem for me.